# Ios Slow Mo Video Play at normal speed in avplayer

Tags: ios, swift, video, visual-studio-2015, avplayer

i am using a video which is recorded in slow mo in camera app than i am selecting it for upload so before upload i play it in preview in avplayer screen than it play at normal speed slow mo effect removed

this is the code for play

` let assets = AVAsset(url: withFileURL)

```
    guard let videoTrack = assets.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
        // Handle the case where video track is not found
        return
    }
    
    
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: assets)
    playerItem?.preferredPeakBitRate = Double(videoTrack.nominalFrameRate)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    
    
    player!.rate = videoTrack.nominalFrameRate
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(itemDidFinishPlaying(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
    
    let layer: AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: DeviceSize.width, height: playerView.frame.height)
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    playerView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 1)`
```

is their any answer because most of on many sites don't works

Comment: “Recoded in slow mo” just means that it has 120 FPS it doesn’t say what the player’s frame rate is. You should be able to adjust the AVPlayer’s rate to whatever you want.

Comment: @GarejaKirit What is meaning of `player!.rate` here (I don't use Swift)? What happens if you set it to `player.rate = 1.0` _ie:_ is it at normal "slo-mo" speed?

Comment: even i also don't know i see that in somewhere

Comment: i find somewhere that we have to export that video first at somewhere other and than we can use it but still slow mo removed